# Dispose of a resource asynchronously in the unsubscribe function

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I want to asynchronously dispose of a resource in the `unsubscribe` function of an observable. For example:

```
// rxjs 6
let observable = Observable.create(sub => {
    let resource = new Resource();
    return {
        async unsubscribe() {
            await resource.dispose();
        }
    }

};
```

The problem is that because the `unsubscribe` function isn't supposed to return a `Promise`, nothing will await it so the `unsubscribe` function will be "over early", before the resource is fully disposed of. This can cause behavior that shouldn't happen while the resource is being disposed of.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Which behavior could happen that "shouldn't happen"? Once you `unsubscribe` a subscription, you can not do anything anymore with that subscription. Then probably you may let the "teardown function" returned by `create` take the time it needs to dispose the resource. Apologies if I have misunderstood your point.

Comment: @Picci Once the subscription is over, logic to create a new resource or destroy a dependency resource (using rxjs operators) can execute while the existing resource is still being disposed. I'll add a code example a bit later.

Comment: It's not possible to receive confirmation that asynchronous operations within an unsubscription teardown have completed. That means that any waiting would need to be performed when you create the resource. You should create a factory that's aware of your cannot-create-whilst-disposing constraint. In any case, even if it were possible to be notified that async ops within the teardown have completed, callers could still violate your constraint be subscribing multiple times. So I think this would be best represented using a factory that prevents multiple resources being created, etc.

Comment: See the ensuing discussion/feature suggestion at [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4222).

Answer (score 0):

There is no hint [in the RxJS source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subscription.ts) that the result of `Subscription.unsubscribe` could be used for awaiting asynchronous code executions.

We see `unsubscribe` may return an `errorObject` that would be cought and treated, but it isn't returned by the unsubscribe function to the consumer itself, so there's no chance on waiting for that.

It also seems to be implemented this way by design. The [Observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html) states:

> When an observer issues an Unsubscribe notification to an Observable, the Observable will attempt to stop issuing notifications to the observer. It is not guaranteed, however, that the Observable will issue no notifications to the observer after an observer issues it an Unsubscribe notification.

This suggests, that the `unsubscribe` notification is not supposed to guarentee the completeness of the Observable in any way.

Alternatively, the `complete` notification seems to be what we are looking for. Semantically, it seems to fit the requirement, as it indicates that the Observable has reached its final lifecycle state.

**EDIT**

After trying out my previous approach I noticed that the `complete` notification wouldn't reach the subscriber after `unsubscribe` was used, so that's also not an option. I think there is no solution for the requirement at this point.